# Finding discontinuities in the DateTime List, C #, LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datetime

The algorithm is based on finding the missing dates in a DateTime list and grouping blocks of dates if they are a second apart or has other time interval

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
Random rnd = new Random();
List<DateTime> datesList = new List<DateTime>();
List<List<DateTime>> segregatedList = new List<List<DateTime>>();
var oneYear = 60*60*24*365;
///////////////////// INPUT GENERATE /////////////////////
for (var i = 0; i < oneYear; ++i)
{
    if (rnd.Next(1, 5) == 4) continue;
    datesList.Add(startDate.AddSeconds(i));
}
/////////////////////// ALGORITHM ///////////////////////
segregatedList.Add(new List<DateTime>());
var difference = datesList[1] - datesList[0];
var j = 0;
var lastIndex = datesList.Count - 1;


for (var i = 0; i < datesList.Count; ++i)
{
    segregatedList[j].Add(datesList[i]);

    if (i == lastIndex) continue;
    if ((datesList[i + 1] - datesList[i]) == difference)
    {
        difference = datesList[i + 1] - datesList[i];
        continue;
    }
    segregatedList.Add(new List<DateTime>());
    ++j;
}
```

I wonder if there is ability to write this code in LINQ.

Comment: Can you please describe, in detail, what this algorithm is meant to do?

Comment: The line `var difference = datesList[1] - datesList[0];` is probably wrong in the case that the second value has been skipped in the `if (rnd.Next(1, 5) == 4) continue;` line.

Comment: The line `difference = datesList[i + 1] - datesList[i];` is just redundant.

Comment: This isn't finding the missing dates. This is grouping blocks of dates if they are a second apart (or multiple seconds based on the initial calculation of `difference`.

Comment: Does this original code actually do what it is supposed to do? Does it work the way you want, so all you want is to replace as much of it as possible with LINQ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I assume that you actually just want to group by date/times that are a second apart then this is the LINQ version:

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now;
Random rnd = new Random();
var oneYear = 60*60*24*365;

List<DateTime> datesList =
    Enumerable
        .Range(0, oneYear)
        .Where(i => rnd.Next(1, 5) != 4)
        .Select(i => startDate.AddSeconds(i))
        .ToList();

List<List<DateTime>> segregatedList =
    datesList
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            datesList
                .Take(1)
                .Select(x => new List<DateTime>() { x })
                .ToList(),
                (a, x) =>
                {
                    if (x.Subtract(a.Last().Last()) == TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1.0))
                    {
                        a.Last().Add(x);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        a.Add(new List<DateTime>() { x });
                    }
                    return a;
                });
```